# Defining Dimensions resource in Android - need clearification please

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have created a UI that requires some font adjustment for small screens. From what I understand, in order to achieve such scaling, I must create a "diemen.xml" inside both values-normal and values-small directories.
The   syntax seems pretty straight forward but what I dont understand is how does Android know where to get the correct values from. Is there a Java code that needs to be added?

For an exmaple:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
```

How would it know if it's normal sized screen or small?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android figures this out automatically when it starts your app on a particular device. If the device configuration is small, it will bind `@dimen/textview_height` to the value in `values-small`, etc. You don't need to provide any Java code for this to happen. The details of how this is done are described in the section [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) of the guide topic [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). You should also read the document [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), which discusses what happens to your app is running when the device configuration changes.

Comment: @user1571299 - If this answers your question, you might mark it as the solution :).

Comment: Sorry about that buddy, first timer on StackOverflow :)